# How do I turn on Option Strict / Infer in a VB.NET aspx page without a code behind file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, option-infer

Umm, I guess my questions in the title:

How do I turn on Option Strict / Infer in a VB.NET aspx page without a code behind file?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Strict="true" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the top line to

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" strict="True" %>
```